# Eclipse 3.6, turn off autocomplete for Salesforce (force.com)

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com

I'm using the force.com (Salesforce) plugin in Eclipse.
Is there a way forcibly turn off autocomplete?  (Typing a quote makes the end pair automatically appear.  This drives me crazy)

In eclipse I can turn this off for individual languages but the preferences > force.com section doesn't expose this.  I'd be happy if autocomplete was forcibly turned off everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is in the "Editor" preferences (search for `editor` and then look for `Typing` below the editor of your language).

For Java, that would be Java -> Editor -> Typing -> Automatically close.

Comment: Nod, this is how you change the editor prefs for .java files but it doesn't work for .cls (Salesforce apex) files.

Comment: It might be derived from some other editor; try to change the setting in other editors. That might have the desired effect. I don't have Salesforce installed, so I don't know what you see on your screen.